# How to submit request to server without needing response

Tags: java, javascript, excel, spring-mvc

Objective: generate excel report.
i call a controller(JAVA) after clicking submit button from UI. After that, i populate data using procedure and do manipulation in service layer.which takes a long time, due to which i get gateway timeout error on UI (there is some amount of load on server).
So, now i was planning to call controller from UI and tell the user that excel report will be emailed to you, such that user wont wait on that screen for report.

Comment: Did you encounter any problems when executing this plan?

Comment: You need job to process this in background.

Comment: I am not sure how should i achieve this.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal yes i want to do the processing in the background & user should continue his/her work on the application. i just dont want user to wait on the screen for obtaining the report.i'll be emailing the report off code to the user when processing completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do asynchronous task using spring with `@Async` annotation. for more detail you can have a look section [25.5.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) in spring.

Answer (score 0):

Once user submits request from UI, just make an entry in database from your controller and give message to user saying "We have received your request and excel will be emailed to you".

Now in background there is job which is running, you can write this job at server side using Thread or better use Spring Batch. This job will do following

1) This will be continuously running thread, which will check is there any new entry from UI in this table, by some flag or so you can find this.

2) This job will generate excel file and email to customer

3) Once file is emailed, update flag = false in database, so that next time this job will take only flag = false records for next time processing.

Comment: @JigarParekh i am using spring 2.5.6
any other approach?

Comment: Above said approach, is better in production considering load on web server, performance, synchronization, data consistency. As it is proven one and used in many of real life projects.

Comment: i guess i'll go with JMS queue style implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a java program that would populate your excel sheet and rest of the things. Then in your servlet use

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*run your java program */);
```

this would create a parallel process and your servlet will end